# How to pass sql rows to array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How do I make an array of the sql rows please help I am new to PHP?

```
$data = null;
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $SurveyTitle = $row->SurveyTitle;
    $SurveyId = $row->SurveyId;
    $data =array('lidata' => '<li id=' . $SurveyId . '><a href=' . $SurveyTitle . '>' . $SurveyTitle . '</a><li>',);
  }
  return $data;
}
else
{
  return $data;
}
```

**EDIT:** I need to pass the lidata to my view

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Add new Survey</a></li>
  <?php echo $lidata;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What issue you facing with above code ? Can you be more clear ?

Comment: have you any error? what you getting after return result try with remove comma after <li>');

Comment: Why you not return if($query->num_rows > 0 ){ return $query->result_array();} and use foreach() for this result array in your controller/view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instaead if `$query->result()` use `$query->result_array()`

your function will be something like this

```
$data = null;
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: I need to pass the li elements to front end

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to store mysql results into an array you need to do this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
$allResults = $query->result_array();
```

Thats all, just check it:

```
var_dump($allResults);
```

More information about *Codeigniter database helper* you can find here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html